# Add image UIBarItem to UINavigationController or alternative

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` with a left and a right button on an app being used as a remote control for a piece of hardware. I would like to show that the hardware is connected to the app by displaying an icon in the navigation bar to the left of the right button. From the documentation it looks as though I can only add `UIBarButtonItems` which make me suspect there is another, more conventional place for my 'connected LED' indicator.

So my question is can I display an icon in a `UINavigationController` navigation bar and if not where should I display it?

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationBar` is a subclass of `UIView`, so you can add items to it like this:

```
[navBar addSubview:whatever];
```

The navigation bar is a property of the navigation controller (i.e. you can reference it like this `self.navigationController.navigationBar`).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a "conventional place" for something like this. :)

I suspect this 'connected LED' should be displayed on all views, regardless of the current view (and its `UINavigationItem`). If that is correct, the easiest way would probably be to NOT put that icon in the actual `UINavigationBar`, but place it as a separate `UIView` in the `UINavigationBar`'s **superview**.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to just create a uiview programatically and add it as a subview of the navbar

```
UIImageView *connectedView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"connected-icon.png"]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:connectedView atIndex:0];
[connectedView release];
```

if insertSubview doesn't work as you expect try addSubview:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:connectedView];
```

You probably want to create the connectedView as a property though so you can (more) easily remove it when you are no longer "connected".

[see this other examples of the approach](http://www.icab.de/blog/2009/10/13/adding-any-kinds-of-ui-elements-into-a-uinavigationbar/)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
[[[yourViewController viewControllers] lastObject] navigationItem].titleView = yourImageView;
```

worke for me in customising navigation bar in mail controller. Hope you get some idea from here.